# How to push form-control beside paragraph

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to push my `form-control` to the left beside of my paragraph. Which won't work it always put below of the paragraph.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">

          <div class = "panel-body">
                <p class = "thicker">STUDENT ID</p>

                <div class = "col-xs-3">
                    <input class = "form-control" name = "search">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div>
<div>
```

Comment: can you use col-xs-3 class on p tag

Comment: @Naresh217 work's fine but it doesn't push beside the paragraph also it removes the bold text.

Comment: Use col-xs-3 as @Naresh217 mentioned and put your p tag and under  <div>input</div>. Can you elaborate a bit more the bold text?

Comment: @RatHat I mean the paragraph has a `class = "thicker"` for bold text. If I put `col-xs-3` my `class = "thicker"` will be remove. Is it possible two class within div?

Comment: You could have two classes for a tag say `<p class = "thicker col-xs-3">Student ID</p>` no problem. Also put the <p> tag under `<div class="col-xs-3">...</div>`

Comment: @RatHat It works properly but how to move `"form-control"` beside paragraph?

Comment: Beside you mean? Distance/space between P tag and form-control. If so you have to play with width on paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add col-xs-3 to your p tag and change the order of the elements inside the panel-body from

```
<div class = "panel-body">
    <p class = "thicker">STUDENT ID</p>
    <div class = "col-xs-3">
        <input class = "form-control" name = "search">
    </div>
 </div>
```

to

```
<div class = "panel-body">
    <div class = "col-xs-3">
        <input class = "form-control" name = "search">
    </div>
    <p class = "thicker col-xs-3">STUDENT ID</p>
 </div>
```

**UPDATE** Using bootstrap built in functionality
Bootstrap has already a functionality for what you are trying to do see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal . Using the built in functionality might make things easier for you in the future when the window is being re-sized, etc. Here is what the code will look like

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">
           <div class = "panel-body">
               <form class="form-horizontal">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="studentID" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Student ID</label>
                       <div class="col-xs-3">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```